# When encoding to MP3 in ShineRecorder, encoding stops if volume is too high

Tags: actionscript-3, jrecorder, shinemp3encoder

Okay, basically we have the [jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery) implemented in our website which provides the ability for us to capture audio in WAV format.

Now, after the capture, we use the [ShineMP3Encoder](https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy) to convert that WAV to MP3 (to save on file size). This all works fine.

Numerous people have encountered an issue in that if the recorded audio levels are too high, MP3 encoding will completely stop and the file will become corrupt/short. When performing this with a WAV, it seems the WAV doesn't care how loud the recorded audio is and will happily play it back as is.

I appreciate my question is *incredibly niche*, but after banging my head against the wall for days, this is my only other option.

For what it's worth, this is the ActionScript that was use to record (it's bog standard ShineMP3 implementation):

```
//recorder.output is outputted from jRecorder
mp3Encoder = new ShineMP3Encoder(recorder.output); 
mp3Encoder.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mp3EncodeComplete);
mp3Encoder.start();
```

Comment: trying to reproduce the bug. Can you provide a wav file? What makes you think its high audio levels?

Comment: Also, are you listening for any ErrorEvent during encoding?

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon To reproduce it, you can simply blow into the microphone as hard as you can. I tried listening to the ErrorEvent but to no avail.

Comment: is there any way to reproduce it using a .wav file you could share? I can't blow in the mic of your app to test, and it seems a bit steep to build an app to test it out. I want to get ShineMP3 to break t isolate the probelm as there, rather than in the jRecorder encoding.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the encoding is running slower than the loop on those tracks, causing an error. 
Try making the encoder run slower and see if that fixes the error.

In the start() method of ShineMP3Encoder.as replace

```
timer = new Timer(1000/30);
```

with

```
timer = new Timer(150);
```

That's line 37 in the current code base.

Comment: Cheers for the response, but I think it's actually throwing an error on encode, but not being raised inside the ActionScript. I will try that and see what happens.